Error con Toast en React Native
Por favor si alguien puede orientarme porque no se ejecuta una parte de mi código, estoy utilizando React Native y  una librería de notificaciones 'react-native-toast-message'
 const showToastEmpty = () => {
    Toast.show({
        type: 'error',
        text1: 'Advertencia',
        text2: 'Por favor ingrese su email y contraseña. ⛔'
    });
}
const showToastError = () => {
    Toast.show({
        type: 'error',
        text1: 'Error',
        text2: 'Error al iniciar sesión. Por favor, inténtelo de nuevo. ⛔'
    });
}

const handleSignIn = async () => {
    if (!email || !password) {
        showToastEmpty();
        return;
    }
    setLoading(true);
    try {
        await signIn(email, password);
        // No es necesario manejar la redirección aquí, 
        // AppContent se encarga de eso
    } catch (error) {
        showToastError();
        console.error(error);

    } finally {
        setLoading(false);
    }
};

en el método handleSignIn se ejecuta normal el showToastEmpty(), si se muestra en mi pantalla del emulador, pero el showToastError(); en el catch no se muestra el Toast solo se muestra en console.error. A que se debe esto ?

Hay que regresar la función showToastError dentro del catch.
Aquí un demo:



const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)

  const showToastEmpty = () => {
    console.log('showToastEmpty')
   /* Toast.show({
        type: 'error',
        text1: 'Advertencia',
        text2: 'Por favor ingrese su email y contraseña. ⛔'
    });*/
}
const showToastError = () => {
  console.log('showToastError')
    /*Toast.show({
        type: 'error',
        text1: 'Error',
        text2: 'Error al iniciar sesión. Por favor, inténtelo de nuevo. ⛔'
    });*/
}

let email = true;
let password = true;
  
  
const handleSignIn = () => {
    if (!email || !password) {
        showToastEmpty();
        return;
    }
    setCount(1);
    try {
        //await signIn(email, password);
        throw new Error('no puedo ir a sign in');
        console.log('in await')
        // No es necesario manejar la redirección aquí, 
        // AppContent se encarga de eso
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('In error', error);
        //aqui falta el return , puedes usar thrown tambien
        return showToastError();
        

    } finally {
        //setLoading(false);
      
      console.log('in finally')
    }
};
  return (
   
    <button onClick={handleSignIn}>
     Click me bruh
    </button>
  
  )
}




ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
      <App></App>  
    )
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>



try/catch en JS
